# How can download latex packages and use it to another computer offline?

Tags: packages

I used MiKTeX,
I have bad internet connection in my home, so I go to cafenet to download latex packages but how to take and download those packages in my computer offline, I would be grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download MiKTeX packages you're interested in from an f.t.p. connection with one of the CTAN mirrors. This is easily done with a software like  `Filezilla` (free software). The location on a CTAN archive of the MiKTeX repository is `./pub/tex/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages`.

In addition of the packages you're interested in that you download on a USB key, in a dedicated directory, you must not forget to download each time the 4 following files  :

- pr.ini,
- miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma,
- miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma,
- and files.csv.lzma.

Last step: declare this directory as a local repository from which all files will be installed or updated (menu `Install from`, `Change...` in MiKTeX Console).

[image]

I hope this is clear. Feel free to ask for any questions.

Configuring Filezilla to download files from MiKTeX repository on the `Dante` site:

[image]
[image]

Comment: many thanks, but i would be grateful if you help us to explain an example step by step, for example `\usepackage{tabu}` how to download this package step by step to other computer offline?

Comment: @JamalWafi: Do you know how to use an ftp software?

Comment: unfortunately, I haven't used ftp before.

Comment: If you want; I can post a screenshot of Filezilla as installed on my system from which I can try to explain the details. If it is installed a computer in the cafenet from where you connect, it will simple. If it isn't, you'll have to put a portable version on your USB key.

Comment: I downloaded and setup the  Filezilla software, how can i use the software to download the MiKTeX packages.

Comment: The software has two windows with an explorer-like view: one for the local computer, and one for the remote directory (MiKTeX  repository). You have to specify the latter to be able to select files and download them. I've posted  screenshots of the way to configure it to connect to the Dante site (`general` tab in the Site manager) and to find on this site the relevant directory (`advanced` tab).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80817/discussion-between-jamal-wafi-and-bernard).